# How do I calculate Spark Statistics that are not of type Double

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, statistics

The spark [documenation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.DoubleRDDFunctions) includes tools for calculating min, max, mean statistics on values of type "double" but how do you handle a spark/java/cassandra scenario when trying to handle column values of type float?

**EDITED** To Show Resolution:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("table",  "someTable")
        .option("keyspace", "someKeyspace")
        .load();

df.groupBy(col("keyColumn"))
        .agg(min("valueColumn"), max("valueColumn"), avg("valueColumn"))
        .show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast it.
`(double) Variable_here` will be the variable's value, but as a double.

Comment: How would I cast it to a double since it is pulled directly into the RDD as a float?